# UILabels not resizing in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uitextview

I have a UITableView that uses prototype cells. The cells have a custom class called dataCell. The custom cells also have three UILabels:idLabel, contLabel, and expLabel. The cells properly resize based on the amount of text in expLabel; however, I cannot get the label itself to resize. Some labels resize when I scroll down; however, they also revert to showing only two lines and omitting text when I scroll back up. Here is my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

dataCell *cell = (dataCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


// the rest of your configure cell

// First Cell Label
[cell.idLabel setText:[idData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.idLabel.numberOfLines = 0;


// Second Cell Label
[cell.contLabel setText:[conData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.contLabel.numberOfLines = 0;



// Third Cell Label
[cell.expLabel setText:[expData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.expLabel.numberOfLines=0;
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [cell.expLabel.text sizeWithFont:cell.expLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(220, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:cell.expLabel.lineBreakMode];
cell.expLabel.frame=CGRectMake(cell.expLabel.frame.origin.x, cell.expLabel.frame.origin.y, expectedLabelSize.width, expectedLabelSize.height);




return cell;

}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
dataCell *cell = (dataCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(220, FLT_MAX);
[cell.expLabel setText:[expData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [cell.expLabel.text sizeWithFont:cell.expLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:cell.expLabel.lineBreakMode];
if (expectedLabelSize.height<43) {
    expectedLabelSize.height=43;
}

return expectedLabelSize.height;  }
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a storyboard and a UITableViewCell then you can just change the auto resizing mask, but if you are doing it programmatically then you will have to set the calculate the text width and height and reset the frame of the labels,

```
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
UIFont* font = label.font;
CGSize maxContentSizeForText = CGSizeMake(maxTextWidth, maxTextHeight);
CGSize stringTextSize = [string sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:maxContentSizeForText lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[label setFrame:CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, stringTextSize.width, stringTextSize.height);
[label setNumberOfLines:1000];
```

your label is probably a property from a xib file or storyboard, and the number of lines is just saying that you want the label to get really really big, since we can't say "infinite" i just generally use 1000 indicating 1000 lines of text maximum

Comment: The UILabel is defined in storyboard as you said. How do I change the auto resizing mask?

Comment: All I had to do at the end was uncheck use autolayout in the file inspector

Comment: You can set a UILabel to handle an infinite number of lines with `[(UILabel) setNumberOfLines:0];`